# Where can i find the question feed URLs for a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, chat, feed

This may sound silly but searching Google and Meta have failed me.

I'm playing with feed settings for the JL&U chat room and can't seem to find the new question feeds for our main and meta sites. Where are they and why are they not linked to from the feeds setting page, at least as example feed URLs?

Comment: At least now Googling and searching meta won't fail for the next person with my bizarre process for feed hunting (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you scroll down to the bottom of the page on main and meta? Look for the RSS icon. It's there.

Comment: I was naively looking for text like "feed" or "url" or "rss" in the chat room settings page, in the internet, and in meta.stackoverflow! Icons below the bottom of the visible portion of the page on my netbook that I wasn't on at the time anyway never occurred to me! (-:

Comment: Oh and feel free to regard this as usability feedback (-:

Comment: RSS is pretty much the exact opposite of usability in every way, and always has been...